R highcharter: show tooltips only when clicking on points
Using R highcharter I want that tooltips only appear when clicking on the data points.
I tried to implement a working javascript code (https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9rj12tfa/)
with R highcharter:
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars

highchart() %>%
      hc_tooltip(list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
      hc_add_series(df,type = "scatter", 
                    hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg),
                    point = list(
                      events = list(
                        click = JS("function() {
                          this.chart.update({
                              tooltip: {
                                  enabled: true
                              }
                          });
                        }"),
                        mouseOut = JS("function() {
                            this.chart.update({
                                tooltip: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            });
                          }")
                      )
                    ))

But unfortunately it does not work.

This is actually 95% of the way there. Just remove hc_tooltip(list(enabled = FALSE)) as this globally disables tooltips (which takes precedence over the tooltip functions inside hc_add_series()) and then change both instances of this.chart.update to this.series.chart.update. It should then behave like the JS Fiddle linked in your original question.
